# Simple Javascript to make an app link (Deep LInk to a mobile App)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, iphone, regex

I need my website to detect that the user has an app installed, and if the user does, to not only open that app, but to also go to a specific area in that app.

For example mycompany.com/user/5/tab/1/section/3 should be regex'd and churned into a AppLink that looks like:

mycompany://user/5/tab/1/section3

Essentially.

The best code I've found seems to be here https://github.com/eusonlito/jquery.applink, but this seems a lot more complex than the rather simple regex + apache rewrite rule I hope to achieve, so just interested if anyone has anything lightweight for the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?)\..*?\/(.*)\/(.*)$
```

You can try this regex to get the form you want.

Replace by :

```
$1://$2$3
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lU7jH1/1